# WINE is not owned by you

Tags: permissions, wine

I have read multiple threads on this topic, but without success. Probably I am making very stupid mistake.

I want to run Office on multiple users on one machine. I successfully installed wine for one user.

But when I run it on second user it fails with error:

```
wine: /opt/windows is not owned by you
```

if I change `chown` to this user all is fine, but the first one loses his rights.

I created a group `wine` and gave permissions, but it seems not to be working

what did I wrong?

```
members wine 
maksim anna
```

and here are permissions:

```
$ ls -l /opt/windows/
total 6632
drwxrwxrwx 2 anna wine    4096 Sep 23 17:02 dosdevices
drwxrwxrwx 7 anna wine    4096 Sep 23 16:57 drive_c
-rwxrwxrwx 1 anna wine 6511990 Sep 23 17:02 system.reg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 anna wine    3428 Sep 23 16:57 userdef.reg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 anna wine  259588 Sep 23 17:02 user.reg
-rwxrwxrwx 1 anna wine     127 Sep 23 16:57 winetricks.log
```

to give a permission I used:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R  /opt/windows/
```

use for all to be sure that will work, unsuccessful

until I will not use explicitly `sudo chown -R maksim:wine /opt/windows/` it will not work for first user.

Comment: [Wine FAQ: Can I install applications to be shared by multiple users?](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Can_I_install_applications_to_be_shared_by_multiple_users.3F)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because a program run through wine cannot be run by another user, because if every user could use the same program with wine the program could access any file from any user, which is a security issue.

An easy way to get what you want is to create a wineprefix with a copy of Office for each user (default is `~/.wine`), then make them run their own version.

Another way of doing this is to create a user specifically to run wine (let's call it `wine_user`) :

```
useradd --no-create-home wine_user
sudo chown -R wine_user /opt/windows/
```

Then you can add your users to the `/etc/sudoers` file to allow them to use wine as `wine_user`, as decribed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/17814/how-can-i-allow-one-user-to-su-to-another-without-allowing-root-access) :

```
maksim  ALL=(wine_user) NOPASSWD:ALL
anna    ALL=(wine_user) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Now that everything is set up, you should be able to run Office with these users (you can put this command in a script or shortcut for simplicity) :

```
sudo -u wine_user wine /opt/windows/office.exe
```

I did not tested this myself, so it might not work as expected. Please tell me if anything is wrong. Note that with this method the files created by the program will be owned by `wine_user` thus shared between your users unless they explicitely run `chown <user> myfile`

Answer (score 0):

Taking a cue from @Batary's answer:

```
sudo adduser --system --no-create-home wine
sudo addgroup wine
sudo usermod -a -G wine $USER
sudo rm -rf /opt/windows    # deletes the wine configuration
sudo rm -f /usr/share/applications/wine.desktop
```

The last command removes the symlink of the Wine application and therefore the Wine application will no longer be visible in the applications menu, but we will return to making it visible thanks to the file `/etc/profile.d/wine-apps.sh` which contains:

```
if [ -z "$XDG_DATA_DIRS" ]; then
    XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/opt/wine-stable/share:/opt/wine-devel/share:/opt/wine-staging/share
else
    if [ -n "${XDG_DATA_DIRS##*/opt/wine-stable/share*}" ]; then
        XDG_DATA_DIRS="$XDG_DATA_DIRS":/opt/wine-stable/share
    fi
    if [ -n "${XDG_DATA_DIRS##*/opt/wine-devel/share*}" ]; then
        XDG_DATA_DIRS="$XDG_DATA_DIRS":/opt/wine-devel/share
    fi
    if [ -n "${XDG_DATA_DIRS##*/opt/wine-staging/share*}" ]; then
        XDG_DATA_DIRS="$XDG_DATA_DIRS":/opt/wine-staging/share
    fi
fi
export XDG_DATA_DIRS
```

In /usr/local/sbin/adduser.local:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
usermod -a -G wine "$1" 2> /dev/null || :
```

to automatically add each user created to the wine group.

In /etc/sudoers.d/autologin-wine-group:

```
%wine   ALL=(wine) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

So that users of the wine group can run a command as wine user without the need to enter a password.

In /etc/environment.d/90wineprefix.conf:

```
WINEPREFIX=/opt/windows
```

so that this path is the default path of the wine configuration.

Reboot.

For the creation of wine configuration, run:

```
sudo -u wine winecfg
```

Enjoy. ;-)